# All finite field $GF(p^m)$ has primitive $9$th root of unity.

Tags: number-theory, finite-fields

I am trying to generalise the question discussed by me in the following link and answered by lfz

[Finite field with $9$th primitive root of unity.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2677687/finite-field-with-9th-primitive-root-of-unity/2677759?noredirect=1#comment5553923_2677759)
A $9$th primitive root of unity is an element of order $9$.

In a cyclic group of order $m$, there is an element of order $d$ iff $d$ divides $m$.

Therefore, as you have found, $GF(p^n)^\times$ has an element of order $9$ iff $p^n\equiv 1\bmod 9$.

Since $p$ cannot be $3$, we have $\gcd(p,9)=1$ and so $p^6\equiv 1 \bmod 9$ and $1 \equiv p^n\equiv p^{n \bmod 6}\bmod 9$.

If we are  interested in which $n$ work for which $p$, then:

- $n \equiv 1 \bmod 6$ implies $p \equiv 1 \bmod 9$
- $n \equiv 2 \bmod 6$ implies $p^2 \equiv 1 \bmod 9$, that is, $p \equiv \pm1 \bmod 18$
- $n \equiv 3 \bmod 6$ implies $p^3 \equiv 1 \bmod 9$, that is, $p \equiv 1 \bmod 6$
- $n \equiv 6 \bmod 6$ implies $p^6 \equiv 1 \bmod 9$, that is, $p \equiv \pm1 \bmod 3$

The cases $n \equiv 4,5 \bmod 6$ reduce to $n \equiv 2,1 \bmod 6$ because $p^6\equiv 1\equiv p^n\bmod 9$ implies $p^{\gcd(n,6)} \equiv 1\bmod 9$.

Now QUESTION is can i say that All finite field $GF(p^m)$ has primitive $9$th root of unity where $m=6n+k$ and $n\ne 0?$

Discussion from the following link

[Finite field with $9$th primitive root of unity.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2677687/finite-field-with-9th-primitive-root-of-unity/2677759?noredirect=1#comment5553923_2677759)

Comment: Don't copy an answer into your question. Add a link instead.

Comment: ok i am adding link....

Comment: @lhf I added link .... Actually you solved the problem already asked but my question was to find for which $GF(p^n)$ contains $9$th primitive root and which does not. But in my question i typed question in different way . Therefore i needed different question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The finite fields with a primitive $9$th root of unity are exactly the fields such that $\Phi_9(x)=x^6+x^3+1$ factors in linear terms. Assuming $p\neq 3$, the degree of the splitting field of $\Phi_9(x)$ over $\mathbb{F}_{p}$ is the least $h\geq 0$ such that $9\mid\left(p^h-1\right)$. Since $\varphi(9)=6$, any field of the form $\mathbb{F}_{p^{6k}}$ with $p\neq 3$ contains a primitive $9$th root of unity.

Comment: But these are not only fields that contains  $9$th primitive root of unity....

Comment: In above link it is said all field $\mathbb F_{p^{6n+k}}$ has 9th primitive root of unitumy

Comment: @neelkanth: $$\mathbb{F}_{p^{6n}}\subset\mathbb{F}_{p^{6n+k}}$$ so if the former contains a primitive $9$th root of unity, so does the latter.

Comment: In general, $\mathbb{F}_{p^m}$ contains a primitive $9$th root of unity iff $p^m\equiv 1\pmod{9}$.

Comment: @ Jack D'Aurizio Ok....it means that i asked in question is correct ?

Comment: @neelkanth: all the fields $\mathbb{F}_{p^{6n+k}}$ with $p\neq 3$ contain a primitive $9$th root of unity, that is correct. But they are not the only ones. $\mathbb{F}_{7^3}$ contains a primitive $9$th root of unity too, for instance.

Comment: Yes thanks ....can you categories all others such fields? Thank you very much ....

Comment: Or should i asked it in different question  form ?

Comment: My answer handles all cases: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2677759/589

Comment: But it does not gives exactly which field ....

Comment: @lhf all i know from the discussion is that all field of the form $\mathbb{F}_{p^{6n+k}}$$(n\ne 0)$ contains primitive $9$th root of unity. But i don't know which types of field does not contains $9$ th primitive root of unity..

Comment: @neelkanth: read carefully the part about the degree of the splitting field of $\Phi_9$. As already stated, $\mathbb{F}_{p^k}$ contains a primitive $9$th root of unity *if and only if* $p\neq 3$ and $9\mid(p^k-1)$.